# create unique number using macros to copy to an excel

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro  to copy random number generates in one excel to another.
The purpose if the macro is to make sure the generates number are unique for each form. How do we make sure on each run the values generates are unique .

Kindly suggest

Comment: may be this link [help](https://superuser.com/questions/1081502/excel-macro-to-copy-rows-with-unique-name-in-column-a-to-accordingly-named-wosks)

Comment: Usually use `Randomize Timer` to **attempt** to make them unique but, being random, they can't be **guaranteed** to be unique.

Comment: Numbers, by definition, aren't unique. Therefore you can only make sure that numbers within a specific context are unique, but you can't make sure that any number that is unique in workbook1 will not occur in workbook2, 3 4 or 5.

Comment: does that mean generating unique numbers via macro is not safe .its like a combination of alpha number example :PO2314.Each number need to be unqiue as each customer can have one number.